# Partially Match Column String Elements between two different columns with the same label (i.e. county) from Two Data Frames Before Merging

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i would like to merge two data frames on a string column called county. one df  is called growth and the other unemployment. the unemployment df has an excess of characters in its county entries. 
i.e. 'Washington County, AL' instead of just 'Washington',
     'Juneau Borough/city, AK' instead of just 'Juneau Borough', 
     'Wrangell City and Borough' instead of just 'Wrangell Borough'
i would like to match them to look like the growth county strings. How do you get the columns to match perfectly, how do you make those changes to all elements of the column in order to get a perfect merge?

````py
```python
    grow.rename(columns={"Countyname":"County","Real Gross domestic product 
    (GDP) by county growth":"2013", "Unnamed: 6":"2014", "Unnamed: 
    7":"2015"}, inplace=True)
    growth = grow.iloc[2:,:]
    #growth.head()
    #growth[growth['Postal']=='LA'].iloc[250:300,:4]
    growth[growth['Postal']=='AK'].iloc[100:150,:4]


    FIPS    County  Postal  LineCode
370 02261   Valdez-Cordova Census Area  AK  1.0
371 02261   Valdez-Cordova Census Area  AK  2.0
372 02261   Valdez-Cordova Census Area  AK  3.0
373 02261   Valdez-Cordova Census Area  AK  4.0
374 02275   Wrangell City and Borough   AK  1.0
375 02275   Wrangell City and Borough   AK  2.0
376 02275   Wrangell City and Borough   AK  3.0
377 02275   Wrangell City and Borough   AK  4.0
378 02282   Yakutat City and Borough    AK  1.0
379 02282   Yakutat City and Borough    AK  2.0
380 02282   Yakutat City and Borough    AK  3.0
381 02282   Yakutat City and Borough    AK  4.0
382 02290   Yukon-Koyukuk Census Area   AK  1.0
383 02290   Yukon-Koyukuk Census Area   AK  2.0
384 02290   Yukon-Koyukuk Census Area   AK  3.0
385 02290   Yukon-Koyukuk Census Area   AK  4.0


    unemp.rename(columns={"Area_name":"County"}, inplace=True)
    #unemp.head()
    unemp.iloc[69:102,:4]

FIPStxt State   County  Rural_urban_continuum_code_2013
69  2000    AK  Alaska  NaN
70  2013    AK  Aleutians East Borough, AK  9.0
71  2016    AK  Aleutians West Census Area, AK  9.0
72  2020    AK  Anchorage Borough/municipality, AK  2.0
73  2050    AK  Bethel Census Area, AK  7.0
74  2060    AK  Bristol Bay Borough, AK 9.0
75  2068    AK  Denali Borough, AK  8.0
76  2070    AK  Dillingham Census Area, AK  9.0
77  2090    AK  Fairbanks North Star Borough, AK    3.0
78  2100    AK  Haines Borough, AK  9.0
79  2105    AK  Hoonah-Angoon Census Area, AK   9.0
80  2110    AK  Juneau Borough/city, AK 5.0
81  2122    AK  Kenai Peninsula Borough, AK 7.0
82  2130    AK  Ketchikan Gateway Borough, AK   7.0
83  2150    AK  Kodiak Island Borough, AK   7.0
84  2158    AK  Kusilvak Census Area, AK    9.0
85  2164    AK  Lake and Peninsula Borough, AK  9.0
86  2170    AK  Matanuska-Susitna Borough, AK   2.0
````

Comment: Which version of Python are you *actually* using?

Comment: the latest 3.7 i think